# How can I redefine (or alter) the bmatrix envrionment such that all entries are flushed right?

Tags: horizontal-alignment, environments, matrices

I've checked around here and have been unable to find anything that solves my problem. There are several other questions that ask similar things, but the solutions do not give a global way to apply the change.

I've been using `\left[\begin{array}{rrr}...\end{array}\right]` for the longest time when typesetting matrices, but recently found `\bmatrix` to be much quicker to accomplish (almost) the same goal. The problem is that I don't like the fact that the entries are centered in their columns instead of flush right. Is there a way I can alter this behavior globally, or maybe `\renewenvironment{bmatrix}` so that I can mimic the behavior with an `array`, but use only `\begin{bmatrix}...\end{bmatrix}`?

For example, I'd like the following two environments to look as close to the same as possible:

```
\left[\begin{array}{rrr}
  x-y & 2 & 3n\\
  2 & 4 & 2\\
  a & x^2 & 2x^2-3
\end{array}\right]

\begin{bmatrix}
  x-y & 2 & 3n\\
  2 & 4 & 2\\
  a & x^2 & 2x^2-3
\end{bmatrix}
```

Comment: Use `mathtools` package. It enhances `amsmath` amd provides this feature.

Comment: I am using `mathtools`... how do I enable this behavior?

Comment: Via `\begin{bmatrix*}[rrr]`.

Comment: \def\bmlp{\left(\begin{array}{rrr}} \def\emrp{\end{array}\right)}. Quicker? :-)

Comment: @percusse intented to say `\begin{bmatrix*}[r]`